# Can't display base64 image in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I recieve the data from server. I encoded the console log result with an online tool and it is correct.

```
axios.get(`https://localhost:44348/api/user/GetFirstImage`)
      .then(res => {
        const img = res.data;
        this.setState({base64File: "data:image/png;base64," + img});
        console.log(this.state.base64File);
      })
```

Then I try to display it in render return (I found this two solutions but neither of them works, I get the default no-image placeholder):

```
<img src={{uri: `data:image/gif;base64,${this.state.base64File}`}} />
<img data-ng-src="data:image/png;base64,{{this.state.base64FileOnlyData}}"/>
```

I really have no more ideas, thank you for your help!

Comment: I think this problem is related to React not being able to handle long strings like a base64 encoded image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you append the `data:` URL scheme prefix and the content type and fact it is encoded in base64 to the base64 data.

> ```
> this.setState({base64File: "data:image/png;base64," + img});
> ```

(Assuming that `https://localhost:44348/api/user/GetFirstImage` returns base64 encoded data rather than the more typical binary data of an image. If it doesn't then you have an extra problem and you need to encode the image).

---

Then here:

> ```
> <img src={{uri: `data:image/gif;base64,${this.state.base64File}`}} />
> ```

You append the `data:` URL scheme prefix and the content type and fact it is encoded in base64 to the URL.

So now you have the preamble applied to the data **twice** which is will break it.

You also can't seem to make up your mind if the image is a GIF or a JPEG. You need to set the correct content-type!

Also, you are trying to set the `src` attribute to an **Object** instead of a **String**. It will get converted to a string — `"[object Object]"` — which will break it in yet another way.

---

This seems to be a very complex approach to the problem though. Is there a reason you aren't serving up a traditional image (instead of base64 data) from `https://localhost:44348/api/user/GetFirstImage` and just setting the `src` to that URL itself:

```
this.setState({imageUrl: "https://localhost:44348/api/user/GetFirstImage"});
...
<img src={this.state.imageUrl} />
```